# HTML5 drag and copy?

Tags: html

I've seen some working code for HTML5 drag and drop but has anyone an example of a drag and copy? I want to drag an element onto a drop element but only copy the element to this location.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

I will stick to the example shown here: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp

*Assuming we have this document:*

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <head>
  <script>
    <!-- script comes in the text below -->
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>

  <div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)"
  ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>

  <img id="drag1" src="img_logo.gif" draggable="true"
  ondragstart="drag(event)" width="336" height="69">

 </body>
</html>
```

**Normal Drag & Drop**

Normal drag and drop has such functions assigned to the respective elements:

```
function allowDrop(ev) {
  /* The default handling is to not allow dropping elements. */
  /* Here we allow it by preventing the default behaviour. */
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  /* Here is specified what should be dragged. */
  /* This data will be dropped at the place where the mouse button is released */
  /* Here, we want to drag the element itself, so we set it's ID. */
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text/html", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
  /* The default handling is not to process a drop action and hand it to the next 
     higher html element in your DOM. */
  /* Here, we prevent the default behaviour in order to process the event within 
     this handler and to stop further propagation of the event. */
  ev.preventDefault();
  /* In the drag event, we set the *variable* (it is not a variable name but a 
     format, please check the reference!) "text/html", now we read it out */
  var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("text/html");
  /* As we put the ID of the source element into this variable, we can now use 
     this ID to manipulate the dragged element as we wish. */
  /* Let's just move it through the DOM and append it here */
  ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
```

**Drag & Copy**

Whereas you'll have to alter the drop function so that it copies the DOM element instead of moving it.

```
/* other functions stay the same */

function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("text/html");
  /* If you use DOM manipulation functions, their default behaviour it not to 
     copy but to alter and move elements. By appending a ".cloneNode(true)", 
     you will not move the original element, but create a copy. */
  var nodeCopy = document.getElementById(data).cloneNode(true);
  nodeCopy.id = "newId"; /* We cannot use the same ID */
  ev.target.appendChild(nodeCopy);
}
```

Try this page: http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_draganddrop
And then append a `.cloneNode(true)` to `getElementById(data)`.

**Switch between Copy & Paste**

You could even do things like in file managers: Ctrl-Key switches from moving to copying:

```
function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("text/html");
  /* Within a Mouse event you can even check the status of some Keyboard-Buttons
     such as CTRL, ALT, SHIFT. */
  if (ev.ctrlKey)
  {
    var nodeCopy = document.getElementById(data).cloneNode(true);
    nodeCopy.id = "newId"; /* We cannot use the same ID */
    ev.target.appendChild(nodeCopy);
  }
  else
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nippey - its great to see this actually works in HTML5!

Comment: ev.ctrlKey was what I was looking for!

Comment: Don't forget to change the id in the created copy.

Answer (score 5):

If you wanted an example using JQuery I have provided [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KWut6/73/). Essentially you just need to bind to the `drop`, `dragover` and `dropstart` events for the DOM objects. You can then use JQuery's build in `clone()` method to duplicate the element.

JQuery also returns it's own events wrapper so you must get the `originalevent` from the JQuery event

```
$('#x').bind('dragstart', function(e) {
    e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'copy';
    e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData('Text', '#x');
});

$('#drop-box').bind('drop', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    $(this).html($(e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData('Text')).clone());

    return false;
}).bind('dragover', false);
```

Comment: Hey thanks BeRecursive - this would totally work ! I was hoping to use the  HTML5 native drag and drop features.

Comment: These should bind to the HTML5 Javascript events, this isn't using JQueryUI's ``draggable`` interface.