# Copy file by drag and drop

Tags: javascript, html

I used some tool which allowed me to drag and drop image from webpage X to webpage Y. More precisely assume we have webpage: http://example.com/. And there we have simple images like:  in HTML. We also have http://mypage.com/ where I have some kind of page to upload file to server. I was able to upload image at mypage.com by simple dragging from example.com and dropping at mypage.com in some place.

My question is: How can I achieve behaviour like this with HTML and JavaScript? Is it possible?

Comment: Have you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13007582/html5-drag-and-copy

Comment: dropped cross-tab images should only give the landing page thier URL, not the image data that you would need to upload...

Comment: it would be enough. How to do it? When I have url I can download it on server side

Answer (score 0):

In short - no, not possible with pure Javascript \ HTML.

The reason is that each page \ tab is restricted to it's own 'stuff' (so one page \ tab on your browser can't interact with a different page \ tab using Javascript and\or HTML) - regardless of the domain (so won't work even if the two tabs are on the same domain).

However, depending on your browser, it's possible that your browser will actually allow this behavior - just like you can drag and drop a file from windows explorer to any webpage (or other application for that matter). But this would be a browser \ OS dependent feature - and not something that can be implemented through pure Javascript \ HTML.

- If what you're trying to accomplish is just to drag-and-upload from one page to another, perhaps searching for a browser add-on would work better for you ?