# minimize onDrop, onDragover, Draggable and onDragStart

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a site with a Drag and Drop design, created after [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13007582/html5-drag-and-copy). It looks like you need to add the ondragover, ondrop, draggable and ondragstart 'functions' to the elements you want to be draggable (not all of them of course, just the ones you need). Is it possible to write this smaller, so you dont need to add it to every element?

Comment: Do you know about class selectors?

Comment: Have you tried something....?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create an array of ids and loop through ids then attach event listeners to them.

```
const ids = ['div1', 'div2', 'div3', 'div4'];

ids.forEach(function(id) {
   document.getElementById(id).addEventListener('drag', function( ev ) {
       ev.dataTransfer.setData('text/html', ev.target.id);
   }, false);
}
```