# How can I prevent multiple items from being dragged using draggable in JS?

Tags: javascript, user-interface, draggable

I'm implementing a drag and drop system in JavaScript. It works great but I have noticed that, sometimes, multiple items get dragged and dropped (see picture below). Is there any way I can prevent this from happening and constrain it so only one item can be dragged and dropped at a time?

[image]

Comment: It would help a lot if you could send your code.

Comment: As of now my code is essentially a tweaked version of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13007582/html5-drag-and-copy/13008017. Although, I am assuming there is a sweet css trick I can do. Just still new to JS and HTML