# Drag-n-Copy Data from one div to the next?

Tags: javascript, html, css, copy, draggable

Hoping to get some help on drag and copy operation from one contenteditable div to the next. Similar to how you can drag and copy in a spreadsheet. The user should be able to enter some data in the divs and drag and copy it to other div elements.

Got a lot of help on this code from Nippey at this link (but it's not exactly what I need).  [HTML5 drag and copy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13007582/html5-drag-and-copy)

Would appreciate any help :).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      #div1,
      #div2,  
      #div3 {
        float: left;
        width: 100px;
        height: 35px;
        margin: 10px;
        padding: 10px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        cursor: pointer;
      }
    </style>
    <script>
      function allowDrop(ev) {
        /* The default handling is to not allow dropping elements. */
        /* Here we allow it by preventing the default behaviour. */
        ev.preventDefault();
      }

      function drag(ev) {
        /* Here is specified what should be dragged. */
        /* This data will be dropped at the place where the mouse button is released */
        /* Here, we want to drag the element itself, so we set it's ID. */
        ev.dataTransfer.setData('text/html', ev.target.id);
      }

      function drop(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData('text/html');
        /* If you use DOM manipulation functions, their default behaviour it not to 
       copy but to alter and move elements. By appending a ".cloneNode(true)", 
       you will not move the original element, but create a copy. */
        var nodeCopy = document.getElementById(data).cloneNode(true);
        nodeCopy.id = 'newId'; /* We cannot use the same ID */
        ev.target.appendChild(nodeCopy);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>Drag and Copy</h2>
    <p>Drag and Copy Entered Data from one cell to the next.</p>

    <div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" contenteditable="true"></div>
    <div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" contenteditable="true"></div>
    <div id="div3" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" contenteditable="true"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```