# Copy element when dropping element. Drag and Drop

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am dropping some element and move to another list.
How to move 2nd element to the second list and stored in the first list.
How it work now.

**Before moving the 2nd element to the second list.**

[image]

**After moving the 2nd element to the second list.**

[image]

**How it should work**

The 2nd element is moved to the second list and stored in the first list.
[image]

```js
const draggables = document.querySelectorAll('.draggable');
const containers = document.querySelectorAll('.container');

draggables.forEach(draggable => {
  draggable.addEventListener('dragstart', () => {
    draggable.classList.add('dragging');
  })

  draggable.addEventListener('dragend', () => {
    draggable.classList.remove('dragging');
  })
})

containers.forEach(container => {
  container.addEventListener('dragover', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const afterElement = getDragAfterElement(container, e.clientY);
    const draggable = document.querySelector('.dragging');
    if (afterElement == null) {
      container.appendChild(draggable);
    } else {
      container.insertBefore(draggable, afterElement);
    }
  })
})

function getDragAfterElement(container, y) {
  const draggableElements = [...container.querySelectorAll('.draggable:not(.dragging)')]

  return draggableElements.reduce((closest, child) => {
    const box = child.getBoundingClientRect();
    const offset = y - box.top - box.height / 2;
    if (offset < 0 && offset > closest.offset) {
      return { offset: offset, element: child }
    } else {
      return closest
    }
  }, { offset: Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY }).element
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  background-color: #333;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

.draggable {
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  cursor: move;
}

.draggable.dragging {
  opacity: .5;
}
```

```html
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <script src="script.js" defer></script>
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <p class="draggable" draggable="true">1</p>
    <p class="draggable" draggable="true">2</p>
  </div>


  <div class="container">
    <p class="draggable" draggable="true">3</p>
    <p class="draggable" draggable="true">4</p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nobody will be able to help you if you don't provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("text/html");
  /* If you use DOM manipulation functions, their default behaviour it not to 
     copy but to alter and move elements. By appending a ".cloneNode(true)", 
     you will not move the original element, but create a copy. */
  var nodeCopy = document.getElementById(data).cloneNode(true);
  nodeCopy.id = "newId"; /* We cannot use the same ID */
  var target = ev.target;
  while( !target.classList.contains('container')){
  target=target.parentElement;
  } 
    target.appendChild(nodeCopy);
}
function drag(ev) {
  /* Here is specified what should be dragged. */
  /* This data will be dropped at the place where the mouse button is released */
  /* Here, we want to drag the element itself, so we set it's ID. */
  ev.target.id="one"
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text/html", ev.target.id);
}

function allowDrop(ev) {
  /* The default handling is to not allow dropping elements. */
  /* Here we allow it by preventing the default behaviour. */
  ev.preventDefault();
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  background-color: #333;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

.draggable {
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  cursor: move;
}

.draggable.dragging {
  opacity: .5;
}
```

```html
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <script src="script.js" defer></script>
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container 1" onDrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <p class="draggable" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">1</p>
    <p class="draggable" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">2</p>
  </div>


  <div class="container 2" onDrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <p class="draggable" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">3</p>
    <p class="draggable" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">4</p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I managed to put this togheter you can play with it and adjust the styles.
I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13007582/html5-drag-and-copy) very helpful