# How to prevent element dragged from leaving its place

Tags: html, css, drag-and-drop, drag

Please check the live code:

I am trying to make a drag and drop but dragged item must be duplication (not moved from one place to another)

```js
let injectableEL = ''
function onDrag(ev) {
   console.log('onDrag', ev.target);
   injectableEL = ev.target
  // ev.preventDefault();
  
}

function onDrop(ev) {
  el = document.getElementById("title");
 
  
  var span = document.createElement('span');
  span.appendChild(document.createTextNode("x"));
 
  var ul =  ev.target;
  ul.appendChild(injectableEL);

}


 

function onOverDrop(ev) {
 
  ev.preventDefault();
}
```

```css
ul, li{border:1px solid green}
.mystyle {padding:5px; background:red; cursor: grab;}
.container-left, .container-right {width:45%; margin-left:1%; float:left}
```

```html
<h4 id="title"> <span><b> Title </b></span> </h4>
<div class="container-left">
  <ul>
    <li class="A" 
        draggable="true" 
        ondragstart="onDrag(event)">A</li>
    
    <li class="B"  
        draggable="true" 
        ondragstart="onDrag(event)">B</li>
    
    <li  class="C"  
        draggable="true"
        ondragstart="onDrag(event)">C</li>
    
    <li class="D" 
        draggable="true"
        ondragstart="onDrag(event)">D</li>
  </ul>
</div>


<div class="container-right">
  <ul>
    <li> Regression
      <ul ondrop="onDrop(event)" ondragover="onOverDrop(event)" style="height:50px">
       
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li> New Feature
      <ul ondrop="onDrop(event)" ondragover="onOverDrop(event)" style="height:50px">
       
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li> Hot fix
      <ul ondrop="onDrop(event)" ondragover="onOverDrop(event)" style="height:50px">
        
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

In the example I am sharing, once the user drags any letter and drops it on the side, the letters disappear from original place.

I am try to keep them as they are, possible just change the color to indicaate it has been moved.

How can I do this?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13007582/html5-drag-and-copy

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML5 drag and copy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13007582/html5-drag-and-copy)